# Is this valid English: "it can help the learner generalize better"?

Tags: grammaticality

It sounds  a bit off, but I am not sure if it valid or not.  It was likely written by a native French speaker.

After viewing the comments, I am including the full sentence:

> It has been shown to be a good regularizer for supervised learning (Erhan et al.,2010), meaning that it can help the learner generalize better, especially when the number of labeled examples is small.

Comment: "What" can help? More context is required in order to provide an answer, as it stands the phrase sounds quite odd, but it might make sense if we knew what can help the learner.

Comment: It's 'valid English' from a grammatical viewpoint. As Mari-Lou A says, that doesn't make it acceptable.

Comment: _Help_ can take an infinitive complement with or without _to_.

Comment: I disagree with those who have suggested that it *sounds quite odd* or that it is not necessarily *acceptable*. As it is, it is fine English, IMO, and not odd at all. The problem with it is that it does not stand alone: to be really meaningful to us we would want to know a little more about the context.

Comment: Wrt the full sentence: That too has correct grammar and is meaningful. That said, it is a poor sentence, wreaking of opaque, pompous [academese](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=academese+examples).

Comment: @Drew Out of curiosity, how would you have written it?

Comment: 1. What or who showed this? Call that X. Say *X has shown...* (perhaps *We have shown...*). Or perhaps just *shows*. 2. What is meant by a *regulizer*? If that is a technical term defined in the paper then leave it as is. If not, substitute simple English for its meaning. 3. Split the sentence after the Erhan reference, with either a period or a colon, and drop *meaning that*. 4. Maybe drop the whole first part: instead of saying *Blah, meaning foobar* maybe write just *foobar*. 5. Say *few labeled examples* instead of *the nmber of... is small*. Etc.

Comment: Yup. But contrary to popular belief, academese is not a requirement for scholarly papers. The best papers are clear, to the point, and uh, actually say something worth reading. ;-)

Comment: The statement can be rewritten as: *It has been shown to be good at generalizing [the subject] for learners, especially when the number of labeled examples is small*. Or: *Within a small group of labeled examples, the supervised learner can comprehend the gist of [the subject]*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer: It is a valid English sentence. The grammar is correct, and it means something. It even means something unambiguously. However, without the context, the referent of *it* is unknown. The sentence has essentially the same as structure as this one:

- *Jujubes can help you answer quicker.*

(Did you really mean to ask a yes/no question, or did you want to know something else?)

Comment: It was just a yes/no question.  I thought "generalize better" sounded odd.  I'm a native French speaker too.  It is clearly valid in French, but I wasn't sure if the direct English translation was also valid.

Comment: I actually had to check on the [web](http://www.english-test.net/forum/ftopic488.html) if "quicker" is acceptable.

Comment: I also added the full sentence in the post.

Comment: Anyone claiming that *quicker* cannot be used as an adverb needs to have his or her learning generalized...